# Connectedness of natural numbers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there any topology (or metric) on $\mathbb{N}$ that makes it connected (other than, trivially, the indiscrete topology)? (Clearly under the usual discrete topology the natural numbers are disconnected, but what about others?)

Comment: Give it only two open sets $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{N}$.  There are other more interesting examples too.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I meant more interesting than just that trivial example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the topology whose base is $\{ a + b\mathbb{N_0} : (a, b) = 1\}$, where $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. This is called the [Golomb space](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/700933/Toposym_01-1961-1_41.pdf). It is even Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the topology whose open sets are $\emptyset$ and all the subsets containing $1$.

Comment: Yes!  These "particular point" spaces can give some really interesting/simple counterexamples.